# Reuse matrix in glm?

Tags: c++, matrix, glm-math

I have a `glm::mat4` field in a class of mine representing a model transformation matrix, and I would like to update the transformation every frame. However, I would like to reuse the matrix in this field every time I update the transformation, instead of setting it to a `glm::mat4()`, which I imagine would waste more and more memory as the matrix that was stored there is assigned over. Am I imagining this leak? Is there a way for me to "re-identity" a matrix in glm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no leak, what you are doing every frame is similar to `int i = 1` every frame;

```
// Im assuming somewhere in your class you have this:
class Example{
    public:
        ...
        void Update();
        void Draw();
    private:
        glm::mat4 m_Model;
};

void Example::Update()
{
    // This will rotate the model 1 degree every time update is called
    m_Model = glm::rotate(m_Model, 1.0f, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0);
}

void Example::Draw()
{
    glUniformMatrix4fv(1, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(m_Model));
    // Draw model etc.. 
};
```

The point is that you don't have to set `m_Model` to `glm::mat4` every frame if you're just keeping it at a static position ( it's always at x,y,z position ), that's equivalent to setting `int i = 1` every single update, it's pointless as it is stored in your classes memory and retains the last value set until the class is destroyed.

Comment: So I shouldn't start from scratch when I update the model matrix, instead choosing to just update the matrix on the fly? I'm basically updating a bunch of fields like `glm::vec3 translation, float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ, glm::vec3 scale` every frame, and then constructing the `glm::mat4` afterwards.

Comment: You should only update the data when you need to update it. Try hard coding the translations at first or only setting them once, then draw your model. Then try setting them every frame, and then setting the transformations when there is a change in data. You'll see the difference and you'll learn what scenario is best for your use case.

Comment: Is there a good way to completely override the translation of the matrix, other than setting those entries manually?

Comment: Yes there is: `glm::mat4 = glm::mat4()` or `glm::mat4 = glm::mat4(1.0f)`